# Configuring windows virtual SMTP server

Tags: iis, smtp, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have a windows 2003 server which is running the IIS(6.0) virtual SMTP server. I have written a event sink for this server to parse and pop incoming e-mails. I'm trying to get the server to accept incoming domains with a wild card. So *.something.com would be accepted by this server.

If I use an alias domain, it wont allow me to use a wild card. If I use a remote domain, I can use a wild card but I have to turn relaying on (which I don't want to do) and it attempts to send itself a message on top of that. If relaying is turned on, i get a error response 5.3.5.

With all that said, I'm looking for a way to configure my server to accept alias domains with wild cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no configuration that allowed me to do this. My solution is ugly, but it works. I kept the relay and only Allowed the server to relay to itself. I also changed the Imessage.envelopeField.MessageStatus to abort on successful read so that it wouldn't be processed by anything other then my sink (thus, not being routed to a "new" destination).

On windows 2003, to have accesses to the Imessage class you need to import cdo.dll.